# Parse and Map 2 Arrays with jq

Tags: json, jq

I am working with a JSON file similar to the one below:

```
{   "Response" : {
    "TimeUnit" : [ 1576126800000 ],
    "metaData" : {
      "errors" : [ ],
      "notices" : [ "query served by:1"]
    },
    "stats" : {
      "data" : [ {
        "identifier" : {
          "names" : [ "apiproxy", "response_status_code", "target_response_code", "target_ip" ],
          "values" : [ "IO", "502", "502", "7.1.143.6" ]
        },
        "metric" : [ {
          "env" : "dev",
          "name" : "sum(message_count)",
          "values" : [ 0.0]
        } ]
      } ]
    }   } }
```

My object is to display a mapping of the identifier and values like :

```
apiproxy=IO
response_status_code=502
target_response_code=502 
target_ip=7.1.143.6
```

I have been able to parse both names and values with

`.[].stats.data[]  | (.identifier.names[])` and `.[].stats.data[]  | (.identifier.values[])`

but I need help with the jq way to map the values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole thing can be done in jq using the -r command-line option:

```
.[].stats.data[]
| [.identifier.names, .identifier.values]
| transpose[]
| "\(.[0])=\(.[1])"
```

Comment: Looks great, can you explain the bit that strips the quotes, please? Assuming I want the quotes, what should I do? This bit "\(.[0])=\(.[1])"

Comment: If you want the outermost quotation marks, omit the -r command-line option.  Regarding the last line of the jq program, see "string interpolation" in the jq documentation at https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/ . If you want quotation marks elsewhere, note that you can include escaped double-quotes in the string.